# Java parse a date in the format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm[:ss[.uuuuuu]][+HHMM|-HHMM|Z]

Tags: java, web-services, date, formatting

How can i parse a date that can come in the specified formart.

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm[:ss[.uuuuuu]][+HHMM|-HHMM|Z]
```

I could use the following code for a specific dateformart:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.S").parse(date_collected);
```

But my problem is dealing with the other possibilities

Comment: If by `[..]` you mean they are optional, you'll need to use a number of different `SimpleDateFormat` objects and use the first one that doesn't fail.

Comment: @Sotirios That is correct [..] are returned from a webservice if available. So if i understand you the solution is to create a simpledateformat object and wrap them recursively in try catches?

Comment: Create a wrapper class that has an X amount of `SimpleDateFormat`. The parse would loop through all of those trying to parse the `String`. If it throws an exception, you continue to the next one. If it passes, you return the result immediately.

Comment: Your idea with the catch blocks would also work

Comment: I see, I guess I just try to avoid situations that errors keep being thrown but since that is what should work I will take your approach. How do i accept the comment as an answer?

Comment: Both java.time and Joda-Time resolve to **milliseconds**. If you want to support more than 3 digits of a fractional second, you could try to use the new java.time package in Java 8 which resolves to **nanoseconds** (9 digits of fractional second).

Comment: @BasilBourque I have to use java5 but the above solution works just fine.